# Date not getting the current time of the phone Swift 4

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have this function that calculate the amount of time from the current minute of the phone. I am trying to have a timer go off after this specific amount of time. The way this function is called is through a switch that the user flips in the app and the time should reset it self. Well Im having trouble with my NSDate object getting old values when the switch was flipped before.  Is there a way to reset the NSDate object to zero?

Here is my code for the calculating the current time of the phone.

```
func GetInitialTime(){
    finalTime = 0
    firstTimeCounter = 0
    timeInSeconds = 0
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    var minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    var timeDifference = Int()

    if(minutes == 00 || minutes == 30) {
        print("The minute hand is at zero or thirty.")
    }
    else {
        print("The minute hand is NOT ar zero or thirty")
        print("The minute hand ia at:")
        if minutes < 30 {
            while (!(minutes == 30)) {
                minutes += 1
                timeDifference += 1
            }
            print("Therefore we make the minute hand at zero or thiry: ", minutes)
            print("The time difference we add to the minute is: ", timeDifference)
        }
        else {
            var i = minutes
            while i < 60 {
                i += 1
                minutes += 1
                timeDifference += 1
            }
            print("Therefore we make the minute hand at zero or thirty: ", minutes)
            print("The Time difference we add to the minute is: ", timeDifference)
        }

    }
    finalTime = Double(timeDifference * 60)
    print("The time difference in seconds is:", finalTime)
}
```

And I declare the Date() object here

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
let date = Date()
var timeInSeconds = Int()
var finalTime = Double()
var halfHour = Double(1800)
var firstTimeCounter = Int()
var firstTimer = Timer()
var repeatingTimer = Timer()
var backgroundTask = BackgroundTask()
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
var urlWeb = "http://morrowrenewablesflowdata.com/iOSConnections/Notifications.php"
var downtimes = [String]()
var flows = [String]()
```

Comment: Can you show where you declare `date`? Using Date() would give the time right now.

Comment: This is Swift, use `Calendar`, not `NSCalendar`. Do not use `NSDate`, use `Date`.

Comment: Whoops I meant Date. I am using Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using an instance variable `date` that is a let constant. You don't show the context in which it's set, but I'm assuming it's an instance variable of your class. The fact that it's a let constant means it will never change in the scope in which it's declared. That's almost certainly your problem.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. I declared it inside of the GetInititalTime() function and changed it to var and now it works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you ask a question and somebody provides an answer that solves the problem you should accept the answer. This is a strong convention on this site. (If there are multiple correct answers you should accept the first correct answer, or the **best** answer if a later answer is markedly better than the first correct answer.)